# How to keep IIS Express running after finished debugging?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, iis-express

I'm using IIS 7 express to test a ASP.Net MVC 3 project on my development machine and normally it keeps running after I finished debugging, which is a good thing so that I can perform small tests directly in the browser without needing to run the project again.

But if I choose the option "Enable edit and continue" on the project properties IIS 7 will only run while debugging the project. Is there a way to change this behavior?

Comment: +1 for the hint that turning off 'Enable edit and continue' keeps IISExpress running—thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18794676/20126

Comment: You can use detach instead of stop, here's how to add it to the menu: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14384964/1248565

Comment: you have to way to go: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19767060/921690

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because in order to achieve this, Visual Studio uses a hosting environment that interprets the code being executed.

So, it is only available while debugging.

Comment: now if i have done editing in project the i just need to Rebuilt and Refresh browser , it will work?

Comment: Turning off the new "Enable Edit and Continue" in tools>options>debug  can do the trick.I put this comment to capture attention here because this answer is accepted and says no way for this but in vs2013+ you can do this .

Answer (score 4):

There is global setting in Visual Studio to have 'Edit and Continue' to be off by default for all new projects under Options > Debugging > Edit and Continue.

Answer (score 4):

Just in case if you need this feature (IIS to continue running) in ASP.NET Web Forms, instead of pressing F5 (Run), right-click the start page in Solution Explorer and select 'View in browser'.