# Visual Studio 2015 Preview - Keep IIS Express Running

Tags: iis, iis-express, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to get a decent development experience with Visual Studio 2015 Preview. 
To do that I'd love to have my IIS Express running all the time instead of requiring me to start debugging.

Anyway to do that? Tried command line:

```
IISExpress.exe /path:pathmyproject/wwwroot
IISExpress.exe /site:SiteName
```

and

```
IISExpress.exe /path:pathtomyproject
```

First two give me:

```
Unable to locate project.json
```

Third one

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Not exactly an answer, but if you can `view in browser` instead of `Debug`.

The command for view in browser is: <kbd>CTRL+ SHIFT + W</kbd> (or right click on project and select `View -> View in broswer`.)

IIS Express will start but will **not** close when you exit your browser.

Hope this helps, this is what I do (specially now that build/compile is no required with `roslyn`).

Comment: the key binding doesn work for me. neither does CTRL + F5. But the right click View in browser solved it.

Answer (score 21):

Similar to VS 2013, if you disable Edit and Continue IIS Express will continue to run when you stop your debug sessions.

Open the menu item Tools/Options, look for the Debugging/General option. Scroll down and uncheck "Enable Edit and Continue"

Comment: Since VS2015 update 2, this solution doesn't work anymore.

Comment: This works for me in Visual Studio Professional 2019 (Version 16.1.4)

Answer (score 13):

in the Debug menu > Start without debugging (Ctr + F5)

Answer (score 9):

Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 adds the support to keep IIS Express Running

*For ASP.NET Web Application projects, when "Enable Edit and Continue" checkbox is unchecked, the IIS Express process will no longer stop working every time you stop debugging.*

[Visual Studio Update 3 RC Release Notes](https://www.visualstudio.com/news/releasenotes/vs2015-update3-vs)

Answer (score 1):

"Enable Edit and Continue" checkbox does not exist in visual studio 2015 update 2!
[this is best solution for this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376154/iis-express-immediately-shutting-down-running-site-after-stopping-web-applicatio/14384964#14384964)

Answer (score 0):

I just unchecked Edit & Continue option under project properties -> Web -> Debugger.
I'm using VS2015. It is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurred to me when trying to run a cloned project. The solution that worked to me was installing **Microsoft.NET Core 1.0.1 VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2**.

1. Go to **Tools** --> **Extensions and Updates** --> click **Updates**
2. Look for **Microsoft.NET Core 1.0.1 VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2** and install the update if it is available.