# After installing VS2015 Update 2 I can no longer view website unless I go in debug mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015

Previously when I start website in debug mode and then stop debug mode website would still be visible if I visit like URL (like http://localhost:54123).

Now, I can only see ASP.NET website if I press F5 and stay in debug mode. As soon as I stop debug mode site is no longer available.

In previous versions of Visual Studio this was preventable by turning off Edit and Continue in csproj properties. But now it seems that option is no longer available. I've tried turning off Edit and Continue globally (from Tools -> Options) but this also doesn't help.

How can I configure Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 to act the same way as before update - if I start website I want it to run regardless if I attached debugger or not?

Comment: have you tried `ctrl + f5`?

Comment: Run it without a debugger (Ctrl+F5) perhaps?

Comment: @Lashane Yes... and it works, but that's not the point - I want configure Visual Studio to function the way it did rather than to re-learn everything because devs introduced new bugs with update.

Comment: @kape123 maybe I'm missing something, but it always worked this way. I mean if you start debug (`f5`) and then stop it - web site should stop working, as VS terminates current process and then only way to avoid this was to `detach from process` (at least this how it worked since in 6.0 - 2010). I haven't tried 2015 though

Comment: you can reassign keyboard short cuts, f5 - execute, ctrl+f5 - debug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, seems this is well known bug that riled up everyone. So far the best workaround is using Detach All instead of Stop when you want to shut down debugger.

Other than that upvoting bug report seems like the only option:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2562576/edit-continue-cant-be-disabled-which-causes-iis-express-to-stop-when-the-debugger-is-stopped

But knowing Microsoft this will probably take 6-12 months to get fixed IF we are lucky.

And to those who are tempted to just uninstall Update 2 and hope Update 1 will pop-up - it won't, I just wasted 2 hours on this and my Visual Studio 2015 was completely bugged. So, complete uninstall, clean install of VS2015-Update1 will work; just Update 2 uninstall - unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio loves being a douche. These are the steps I take when it refuses to act normally..
1. Save your work 
2. From the file menu close your solution 
3. Close visual studio 
4. Identify w3wp.exe or something of that nature in task mgr > Details(kill those) 
5. Go to where you deployed that app, if its default it'll be in IIS > Default Web Site > "The name of your website". Click Explore under options delete the app folder

6. Reopen app Clean > Rebuild > Run

Should play nice now