# Visual Studio Debug "This site can't be reached"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

One of my projects has stopped being able to run debug.. From one moment to another I get the response "This site can't be reached" when running the debugger in VS2017. I have tried the following solutions that I found, but none work for me.

- Delete the bin folder
- Clean and rebuild the solution
- Unload and Reload the solution
- delete the .vs folder
- change the port and create Virtual Directory

These are the suggested solutions I find over and over again, but none work for me. Any other suggestions I could try?

NB: This problem only arrises only with one specific application.

Answer (score 3):

I finally found an answer that worked for me [here](https://forums.asp.net/t/2069555.aspx?ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED).

It is suggested to uncheck "Edit and Continue" in the debugger menu. I combined this with (just to be sure) deleting the vs and the bin folders and restarted Visual Studio. I am not sure what the issue was, but it is solved now at least.

Comment: Another thing could be that users that updated to Windows 11 had IIS deactivated from windows features by default. You can activate it again by just searching "Turn Windows features on or off" in your PC and activating IIS again.

Answer (score 2):

The problem for me turned out to be that my web.config had a  rule that was rewriting the URL to use https instead of http.  After I removed the  section from my web.config, I was able to debug the site.