# How to run a web project in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, iis-express, iis-8

In Visual Studio 2013, when I run a web project, I click on "Google Chrome".
In Visual Studio 2017, when I run a web project, the selection is for "IIS Express (Google Chrome)" or "IIS Express" with other browsers like Internet Explorer.
When I click either, I got "This site can’t be reached" error.
I don't think I have IIS Express installed on my machine (It's not listed in Administrative Tools).

Does it mean to run a web project from Visual Studio 2017, I will need to install IIS or IIS Express ?

Thank you

Comment: IIS Express is a normal application, so you should go to Control Panel | Programs for it, not Administrative Tools. "This site can’t be reached" is quite common, but what URL in address bar when that error message is shown? You cannot post an incomplete question.

Comment: Hi, I do see IIS 10.0 Express in Control Panel > Programs. The URL is: http://localhost:59242/ , which is the same URL when I run the web project from Visual Studio 2013 and the page shows up. But, http://localhost:59242/ from VS 2017 returned "This site can't be reached". How do I know if the IIS Express is running ?

Comment: You need to check if VS generates the right applicationHost.config file for this project, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/getting-started/features.html#add-iis-express-from-visual-studio-2015-2017-2019-solution-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you confirmed that IIS express is installed properly on your local machine, I think there is something wrong with the IIS Express configuration file. please refer to the following steps.
Go to the project directory, delete the hidden folder `.vs`, and restart Visual Studio again. In addition, I suggest you uncheck `Edit and Continue` in the debugger menu.
Here is a related discussion.
[Visual Studio Debug "This site can't be reached"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51931398/visual-studio-debug-this-site-cant-be-reached)
https://forums.asp.net/t/2069555.aspx?ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Thank you ! Deleting the hidden folder .vs and uncheck "Enable Edit and Continue" fixed my issue.