# Stopping debugging doesn't actually stop the site application

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

When stopping the debug session the application is still running and I can access it from http://localhost:3825/
the only way to stop the application is to close the solution from visual studio

**What I want**

to stop the application(shut down the application and close http://localhost:3825/) ... So I can test error handling from angular(fronted).

**Expected behavior**

When I click stop debug (using IIS Express) the application would stop (shutdown)

**Environment**

I just start visual studio and open solution and click IIS Express with all the default setting, I didn't change anything

**My tries**

- Tried to use the program rather than ISS Express,still the program is still alive
- Tried to start without debug **<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>** , this build the application in the background and doesn't show any way to shut it, but to close the solution.

If anyone have an idea of what is that behavior coming from please explain it to me.

Comment: Just stop it from the IIS Express icon in the taskbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the IIS Express icon in the taskbar and close the application from there.

OR

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376154/iis-express-immediately-shutting-down-running-site-after-stopping-web-applicatio), OP has the same problem that you are facing except it is the inverse.

**Right click -> Properties -> Web tab -> Check "Enable Edit and Continue"**
should do the trick for you.

Another way to go could be : 
**Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General -> Check "Enable and Continue"**.