# IIS Express process gets terminated while debugging in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, iis-express, iis-10, iis-express-10

While debugging ASP.net core web app in visual studio, after hitting a breakpoint (anywhere for ex. in Startup.cs), after about 5 minutes, IISExpress process terminates and debugger stops.
The only error message related to this, I could see is in event viewer:

IISExpress 10
Visual studio 2022 Professional

Application ‘/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT’ with physical root ‘C:\Users\XXXX\OneDrive - XXXXXX\Documents\XXXXX\apps\YarpTest\WebApi’ failed to load coreclr. Exception message:
Managed server didn’t initialize after 4294967295 ms.

Tried out pretty much all the suggestions available in online forums without much luck (like turning off enable edit and continue in settings, turning on, enable just my code in tools -> options->Debugging -> General, deleting .vs folder etc)

Appreciate your suggestions in getting this IISExpress debug issue resolved.

Comment: https://github.com/search?q=repo:dotnet/aspnetcore%20ASPNETCORE_EVENT_LOAD_CLR_FAILURE_MSG&type=code You might build your own ASP.NET Core module from source code and then debug into the lines about `ASPNETCORE_EVENT_LOAD_CLR_FAILURE_MSG`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `Detach all` menu item in the `Debug` menu，It detached the debugger from the processes being debugged, but does not kill the processes in the progress.

This method is mentioned in this thread, you can check it out and try it:

[IIS Express Immediately shutting-down running site after stopping web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376154/iis-express-immediately-shutting-down-running-site-after-stopping-web-applicatio)

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. My case is different though. My IIS works fine, hosting the web app without any issues if I dont keep the process wait on a break point. Only when its on a break point, it just gets stopped after sometime.

Comment: When running an application in debug mode, some additional features are usually enabled, such as debugger attachment, code tracing, etc. These features take up more system resources or introduce some additional waiting time, so application performance may be affected. I think some possible reasons for this problem:

1. The extra delay causes the application to wait for a longer time at the breakpoint, eventually triggering a timeout error.
2. Breakpoints may cause resource contention or locking issues, which may not occur in non-debug mode because execution is not paused.